# How to detect an MVC app in an HttpModule

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, httpmodule

I am writing an HttpModule. I'm trying to discover how to detect that a request is to an MVC app.

I'm hooked into some of the handlers like this.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication httpApp)
{
    httpApp.PreRequestHandlerExecute += PreRequestHandlerExecute;
    httpApp.PreSendRequestHeaders += PreSendRequestHeaders;
    httpApp.PostRequestHandlerExecute += PostRequestHandlerExecute;
}
```

My PreRequestHandlerExecute needs this conditional.

```
public void PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if isMvc(HttpContext.Current))
    {
        doSomethingSpecificToMvc()
    }
```

isMvc() looks likes this, relying only on the lack of a file extension to detect an MVC request (which is lame).

```
private static bool isMvc(HttpContext ctx)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(ctx.Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"])))
    {
        retVal = true;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

What would be a better way to determine that the request is to an MVC app?

Comment: What is the implementation of doSomethingSpecificToMvc()? I'm curious why you want to make this unusual distinction...

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to look at the HTTP Header and see if there is an entry similar to this.

X-AspNetMvc-Version 3.0

Here is an updated version of isMvc which may work for what you are doing.

```
private static bool isMvc(HttpContext ctx)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    string []header = ctx.Request.Headers.AllKeys;
    if (header.Contains("X-AspNetMvc"))
    {
        retVal = true;
    }

return retVal;
```

}

Comment: Good thought - unfortunately, we suppress headers for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You could determine if the endpoint is an asp.net mvc app by calling the endpoint and checking for a X-AspNetMvc-Version in the response. There is no requirement that this header be on the response, it is placed there by the framework by default. You will have to find hacks like that because each framework will have its own routing system and unique quirks.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this. If the context handler has been populated this works.

```
private static bool isMvc(HttpContext ctx)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    if (ctx.Handler != null && ctx.Handler.ToString() == "System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler")
    {
        retVal = true;
    }

return retVal;
}
```